# HTTP redirect with curl does not resend the same http message

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl, http-redirect

I'm developing an application in which I use libcurl.

I added in my c code the following curl option:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
```

in order to follow http redirection.

when my application send a http message (**first http message**), it receives a http 302 redirect from the server, the libcurl detect with success the redirect information and then send another http message (**second http message**) to the new url but the new http message is not the same comparing to the **first http message**.

How I can make libcurl sending the same HTTP message?

---

**First http message**: communication between my application and the first server till the application get the http redirect message

application  ---->  server1

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.15
Accept: */*
User-Agent: cwmp
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 341
Expect: 100-continue
```

server1 ----> application

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
```

application  ---->  server1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <soap_env:Envelope
xmlns:soap_env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:soap_enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap_env:Header>
      <cwmp:ID soap_env:mustUnderstand="1" />
    </soap_env:Header>
    <soap_env:Body>
      <any:command>any_command_value</any:command>
    </soap_env:Body>
  </soap_env:Envelope>
```

server1 ----> application (redirect message)

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 13 May 2014 11:00:48 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) PHP/5.5.8
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.8
Location: http://192.168.1.133:8080/openserv/serv
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
```

---

**Second http message**: http message sent by my application to the second server after receiving the http redirect

application ---> server2

```
GET /openserv/serv HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.133:8080
Accept: */*
User-Agent: cwmp
Content-Type: text/xml
```

Comment: According to standarts, yes, it is required to send the same message on redirect. However, almost no tools implement the standart. Curl changes request method from `POST` to `GET` on redirect, and yes, it is against standarts, but I don't think you can do anything here except to disable `FOLLOW_LOCATION`, recoginize 302 and 301 response codes and send request with another call to libcurl.

Comment: Per HTTP RFC the server should respond with a 307, not 302.

Comment: CURLOPT_VERBOSE set to 1 would've helped you detect this...

Comment: @n.m. I think you are wronng. in the RFC2616 chapter **10.3.3 302 Found**: `If the 302 status code is received in response to a request other
   than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the
   request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might
   change the conditions under which the request was issued.`

Comment: The same MUST NOT clause is in effect for both 302 and 307. So why choose 307? 302 should be avoided in this case because many clients implement it incorrectly (like 303 instead of like 307). If the server wants the client to repeat the POST, it should respond with 307. If the server wants the client to get an answer with GET, it should respond with 303. 302 is de facto ambiguous (though according to the standard it is not).

Comment: @DanielStenberg libcurl works properly when it receives 307 but it does not send the same http message when receiving 301 or 302. is it possible to configure libcurl in order to send the same http message when it get 301 or 302?

Comment: You've already got an answer explaining how!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to standarts it is required to send the same message on HTTP redirect. However, almost no tools implement the standart. `libcurl` changes request method from `POST` to `GET` on redirect, and yes, it is against standarts, but it is how it works.
Possible solutions:

1. Use `CURLOPT_POSTREDIR` option; it will force `libcurl` to at least also use `POST` method after redirect, I don't know what about `POST` request body.
2. Recoginize 302 and 301 response codes and send request with another call to `libcurl`.